# Add a command into an existent remote console application

Tags: windows, remote, console, windows-command-prompt, ms-dos

I manage to open a console application in a remote computer by using PSTools using *PsExec.exe*.

> C:\PsExec.exe -i 2 -s -d \128.168.500.500 -u username -p password "D:\myApp.exe"

That will open a console application (not just a console) remotely.

Now I would like to execute a command in that remote console application. Is that somehow possible at all?

This is the command I want to run:

> > @start.txt

Answer (score 1):

Sure, start psexec the below way:

```
psexec \\<target> cmd
```

That will then just run a terminal session remotely where you can continue to execute more commands.

Comment: I don't want to start the command line. The command line will get started with whenever I open a .exe. Is there, in that exe, where I want to be able to write a command. Inside that console application.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Okay then copy in a batch file for execution line by line or create a new batch file and call it from the psexec session.

Comment: Also that command “@start.txt” can be executed using just start.txt if it’s in your working directory or path etc of the remote machine , because you’ve specified the interactive switch it should open on the target.

Comment: Could you elaborate it? I don't understand what you said about the batch file. If you update your answer that'd be nice.

Comment: You want to run the first command then be able to execute the start.exe file? Am I correct?

Comment: I have the console application running. Now I want to execute the following command `@start.txt` which points to a text file, not an exe.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain the purpose of executing `>@start.txt`.

Are you trying to collect the logs of `"D:\myApp.exe"` to `>@start.txt`. `>@start.txt` cannot run like as any `.exe`. So if it is going to be a log collector of `"D:\myApp.exe"` then try the below command line.

```
C:\PsExec.exe -i 2 -s -d \128.168.500.500 -u username -p password "D:\myApp.exe" >> @start.txt
```

Or else, please elaborate the purpose.

Comment: Inside that .txt file there are some commands o be interpreted by the .exe. It is in a text file so that the users can customize those commands easily before starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Is myapp.exe reading the command from standard input?  If so, create a text file that contains `@start.txt` and add a redirect for stdin:

```
C:\PsExec.exe -i 2 -s -d \128.168.500.500 -u username -p password cmd /c "D:\myApp.exe <mycmd.txt"
```

(The `cmd /c` syntax ensures that the < redirect applies to myapp, not to psexec.)